# Server Side Language for Scalable TCP-socket application

Tags: tcp, sockets, server-side

Which amongst these would be well suited for a scalable server side TCP socket based Web application.
Java, PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby.

You could base yours answers Primarily on:

- Rapid Application Development.
- Available frameworks(If required) for
  getting the job done.

Secondarily on:

- Performance
- Support

In addition you could add to the above other issues you wish to highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Java and Mina,

http://mina.apache.org

for performance and scalability.

Comment: How fast is development time?
Does the web host need to have Mina?

Comment: It's not for fast prototyping. There is some learning curve. However, you just can't get this kind of performance with a scripting framework. Mina is just a JAR file so you can package it with your server.

Answer (score 1):

Urban Airship recently made an interesting blog post: [500k in Action at Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/08/24/c500k-in-action-at-urban-airship/).

For Rapid Application Development, I'd recommend Python (Twisted or Eventlet) or Ruby (EventMachine). These should be enough to scale to a few thousand (idle) connections. Note that I don't have experience with those libraries myself, and there might be many more.

Scala might also worth looking at. It's good for rapid application development and has good performance (compared to Python or Ruby), but the community and development tools aren't that mature yet.

For very large scalability, you should probably look at Java or Erlang.